# how to use tor in linux kali with other applications

Tags: tor, kali-linux

I want to know how to open applications as nmap and recon-ng  through tor
first I have kali linux v 1.0.9 and tor
I tried using 
    proxychains recon-ng
but all I get is that the normal banner of recon-ng and this
   |DNS-request| www.google-analytics.com 
   |D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--timeout
   |D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--timeout
   |DNS-response|: www.google-analytics.com is not exist
   [recon-ng][default] >
I also tried the command
   torify recon-ng
but I get this error
   /usr/bin/torify: torsocks not found in your PATH.  Perhaps it isn't
   installed?  (tsocks is no longer supported, for security reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Those applications need low level access to the network (at sockets level) in order to be able to craft special packets so they won't work with tor and proxychains. You might be able to use some configurations like nmap tcp connect scan ( -sT ) since it sends normal tcp packets and not just the syn as in the stealth scan.

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same timeout problem

Comment: and I dont understand why does the response come from www.google-analytics.com

Comment: It is possible that the developer of that application you are using is using google analytics to get statistics about the application usage. check the configurations there might be someway to turn it off.